# I need to return the data that matches a variable value

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have the following weather XML data:

```
<weather>
  <current_conditions>
    <condition data="Mostly Cloudy" /> 
    <temp_f data="48" /> 
    <temp_c data="9" /> 
    <humidity data="Humidity: 71%" /> 
    <icon data="/ig/images/weather/mostly_cloudy.gif" /> 
    <wind_condition data="Wind: W at 17 mph" /> 
  </current_conditions>
  <forecast_conditions>
    <day_of_week data="Sun" /> 
    <low data="34" /> 
    <high data="48" /> 
    <icon data="/ig/images/weather/mostly_sunny.gif" /> 
    <condition data="Partly Sunny" /> 
  </forecast_conditions>
  <forecast_conditions>
    <day_of_week data="Mon" /> 
    <low data="32" /> 
    <high data="45" /> 
    <icon data="/ig/images/weather/sunny.gif" /> 
    <condition data="Clear" /> 
  </forecast_conditions>
</weather>
```

I want to return a string based on the day for example, today:

```
string theCondition = doc.XPathSelectElement(
  @"weather/current_conditions/condition"
).Attribute("data").Value;
```

If I have a varible that's = `"Sun"` I want to return the same string as above but  `<forecast_conditions>` where `<day_of_week data="Sun">` and likewise for Mon, Tue, Wed.

If no data is available then i need to `Console.WriteLine("no data")`.

As I am new to programing I want to keep to using `doc.XPathSelectElement` as this stage.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "c#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1):

```
string day  = "Sun";
string path = "weather/forecast_conditions[day_of_week/@data='" + day + "']/condition";

doc.XPathSelectElement(path).Attribute("data").Value;
```

Note that you need to check whether `doc.XPathSelectElement(path)` actually returned a match before you call `.Attribute("data").Value` on it.

Comment: What would be the simplest way to export this to a CSV?

Comment: @dave This is material for a different question.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
string expr =
   string.Format
    ("string/*/forecast_conditions[day_of_week/@data = '{0}']/condition/@data)", 
      weekDay);

string forcastData = (string) doc.XPathEvaluate(expr);
```